# How to make the background color property of a custom view animatable?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer

I want to animate my custom view's background color.

My drawing code is very simple. The `draw(in:)` method is overridden like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class SquareView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        let strokeWidth = self.width / 8
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: self.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        self.backgroundColor?.darker().setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

The `darker` method just returns a darker version of the color it is called on.

When I set the background to blue, it draws something like this:

[image]

I want to animate its background color so that it gradually changes to a red color. This would be the end result:

[image]

I first tried:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
    self.square.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

It just changes the color to red in an instant, without animation.

Then I researched and saw that I need to use `CALayer`s. Therefore, I tried drawing the thing in layers:

```
@IBDesignable
class SquareViewLayers: UIView {
    dynamic var squareColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        layer.backgroundColor = squareColor.cgColor
        let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let strokeWidth = self.width / 8
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: self.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        self.tintColor.darker().setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        sublayer.path = path.cgPath
        sublayer.strokeColor = squareColor.darker().cgColor
        sublayer.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(sublayer)

    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
}
```

But the result is horrible

[image]

I used this code to try to animate this:

```
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "squareColor")
anim.fromValue = UIColor.blue
anim.toValue = UIColor.red
anim.duration = 1
square.layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
```

Nothing happens though.

I am very confused. What is the correct way to do this?

EDIT:

The `darker` method is from a cocoa pod  called `SwiftyColor`. This is how it is implemented:

```
// in an extension of UIColor
public func darker(amount: CGFloat = 0.25) -> UIColor {
    return hueColor(withBrightnessAmount: 1 - amount)
}

private func hueColor(withBrightnessAmount amount: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    var hue: CGFloat = 0
    var saturation: CGFloat = 0
    var brightness: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0

    if getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha) {
        return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation,
                           brightness: brightness * amount,
                           alpha: alpha)
    }
    return self
}
```

Comment: Well, a shape with only 3 points can't be a square.  move(to:..) moves the cursor without drawing, then you have two addLine(to:...) which draws two sides, you seem to be missing at least one side so that one the shape is closed, it forms a square (provided that's your intent).

Comment: As for animating the color, you are indicating to your view that it needs to refresh itself, but there is nothing that is binding the square color to the layer background color.

Comment: Check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064668/animating-calayer-background-color-and-update-model-value

Comment: @ekscrypto My intent is to draw a horizontally inverted "L" shape. Do you mean that I should draw the six sides of the inverted "L" shape and fill it in?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the L shape, I haven't done enough CALayer animations to tell.  You either have to make sure your shape is closed or to tell it not to auto-close the path; something I can't answer.

Comment: @ekscrypto The answer of the post you linked says that I should use an explicit `fromValue`. I am using one right now, am I not?

Comment: Yes, but you are specifying the animation of the layer to use a keyPath of "squareColor", your layer doesn't have such valid keyPath. so your animation does nothing. You either have to bind "squareColor" to "backgroundColor" or to have your animation run on the keyPath "backgroundColor".

Comment: @ekscrypto Oh I see. So the key path parameter refers to a key path in the layer, instead of the view. Thank you? I will try to come up with something.

Comment: Hey @Sweeper, did you see my answer below. It should work really fine. What is your opinion on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you stroke the L-shape with a semi-transparent black instead?

Then you don't have to mess around with redrawing and color calculations, and you can use the basic UIView.animate()

Below the "LShadow" is added onto the SquareView, so you can set the SquareView background color as per usual with UIView.animate()

---

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var squareView: SquareView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        squareView = SquareView.init(frame: CGRect(x:100, y:100, width:200, height:200))
        self.view.addSubview(squareView)

        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 1.0, animations: {
            self.squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

---

SquareView.swift

```
import UIKit

class SquareView: UIView {
    func setupView() {
        let shadow = LShadow.init(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(shadow)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
}


class LShadow: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let strokeWidth = self.frame.size.width / 8
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: self.frame.size.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        UIColor.init(white: 0, alpha: 0.5).setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! I ended up creating another `UIView` subclass called `LShapedOverlay` and added that as a subview of the `SquareView`.  Then I can use `UIView.animate`.

Comment: Can you edit the answer to add some code so I can give you the bounty?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with `CABasicAnimation`.

1. The `keyPath:` in `let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "squareColor")` should be `backgroundColor`.
2. `anim.fromValue` and `anim.toValue` require `CGColor` values (because you're operating on the `CALayer`, which uses `CGColor`). You can use `UIColor.blue.cgcolor` here.

Pretty sure this animation won't persist the color change for you though, so you might need to change that property manually.

Comment: What about the inverted "L" shape that I drew? How can I change the color of that as well?

Comment: Can you provide your implementation of `darker`?

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Using `CAKeyframeAnimation` you need to animate `backgroundColor` property:

```
class SquareView: UIView
{
    let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let frame = self.frame
        let strokeWidth = self.frame.width / 8
        sublayer.frame = self.bounds

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width  - strokeWidth / 2 , y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width - strokeWidth / 2, y: frame.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height - strokeWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0 , y: 0))
        path.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        sublayer.path = path.cgPath
        sublayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        sublayer.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(sublayer)
    }

    //Action
    func animateIt()
    {
        let animateToColor = UIColor(cgColor: sublayer.backgroundColor!).darker().cgColor
        animateColorChange(mLayer: self.sublayer, colors: [sublayer.backgroundColor!, animateToColor], duration: 1)
    }

    func animateColorChange(mLayer:CALayer ,colors:[CGColor], duration:CFTimeInterval)
    {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
        CATransaction.begin()
        animation.keyTimes = [0.2, 0.5, 0.7, 1]
        animation.values = colors
        animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.repeatCount = 0
        animation.duration = duration
        mLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

[image]

**Note:** I have edited the answer so that the shape will always fit the parent view added from storyboard

Comment: Sorry for not describing my goal properly. What I want is not a triangle that changes color. I want a square view, with a darkened inverted-L-shaped area, to change color gradually. See the first two images in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    view.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
} completion:NULL];
```

Swift

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) { 
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my first attempt (that did not work)?

Comment: Why are you updating the layer the Objective-C code, while in the Swift code you're directly manipulating the view? Also just code without any explanations doesn't make it a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have in the code below, two different CAShapeLayer, foreground and background. Background is a rectangle path drawn to the extent where inverted L actually starts. And L is the path created with simple UIBezierPath geometry. I animate the change to fillColor for each layer after color is set.

```
class SquareViewLayers: UIView, CAAnimationDelegate {

    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blue {
        didSet {
            animate(layer: backgroundLayer,
                    from: oldValue,
                    to: color)
            animate(layer: foregroundLayer,
                    from: oldValue.darker(),
                    to: color.darker())
        }
    }

    let backgroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let foregroundLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    func setupView() {

        foregroundLayer.frame = frame
        layer.addSublayer(foregroundLayer)

        backgroundLayer.frame = frame
        layer.addSublayer(backgroundLayer)


        let strokeWidth = width / 8

        let backgroundPathRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width - strokeWidth,
                                                                    height: height - strokeWidth))
        let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(rect: backgroundPathRect)
        backgroundLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
        backgroundLayer.path = backgroundPath.cgPath

        let foregroundPath = UIBezierPath()
        foregroundPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: backgroundPathRect.width,
                                        y: 0))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width,
                                           y: 0))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: width, y: height))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0,
                                           y: height))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0,
                                           y: backgroundPathRect.height))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: backgroundPathRect.width,
                                           y: backgroundPathRect.height))
        foregroundPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: backgroundPathRect.width,
                                           y: 0))
        foregroundPath.close()

        foregroundLayer.path = foregroundPath.cgPath
        foregroundLayer.fillColor = color.darker().cgColor
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    func animate(layer: CAShapeLayer,
                 from: UIColor,
                 to: UIColor) {
        let fillColorAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
        fillColorAnimation.fromValue = from.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = to.cgColor
        fillColorAnimation.duration = 1.0
        layer.add(fillColorAnimation,
                  forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

And here is the result,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had an implementation of changing the background color of view with animation and did some tweak in the source code to add inverted L shape using CAShapeLayer. I achieved the required animation. here is the sample of the view.

```
class SquareView: UIView, CAAnimationDelegate {

    fileprivate func setup() {
        self.layer.addSublayer(self.sublayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup
    }

    let sublayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let strokeWidth = self.bounds.width / 8
        var frame = self.bounds
        frame.size.width -= strokeWidth
        frame.size.height -= strokeWidth
        self.sublayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame).cgPath
    }



    var color : UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        willSet {
            self.sublayer.fillColor = newValue.cgColor
            self.backgroundColor = newValue.darker()
        }
    }



    func animation(color: UIColor, duration: CFTimeInterval = 1.0) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        animation.keyPath = "backgroundColor"
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = 1
        animation.autoreverses = false
        animation.fromValue = self.backgroundColor?.cgColor
        animation.toValue = color.darker().cgColor
        animation.delegate = self;

        let shapeAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        shapeAnimation.keyPath = "fillColor"
        shapeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        shapeAnimation.duration = duration
        shapeAnimation.repeatCount = 1
        shapeAnimation.autoreverses = false
        shapeAnimation.fromValue = self.sublayer.fillColor
        shapeAnimation.toValue = color.cgColor
        shapeAnimation.delegate = self;


        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "kAnimation")
        self.sublayer.add(shapeAnimation, forKey: "kAnimation")
        self.color = color
    }



    public func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "kAnimation")
        self.sublayer.removeAnimation(forKey: "kAnimation")
    }
}
```

You can use the method `animation(color: duration:)` to change the color with animation on required animation duration.

**Example**

```
let view = SquareView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 200, height: 300))
view.color = UIColor.blue
view.animation(color: UIColor.red)
```

**Here is the result**

[image]